# serve postscript file with php script

Tags: php, postscript

I want to give a link to a postscript file, but first I want to make a script that will monitor the downloads of this file. The link has to be 'direct' so I added `.ps` extension to be interpreted by PHP. In the begining the script opens the text file, writes some information and then I don't know what to do.
Basically I have something like this (file `apendix.ps`):

```
header('Content-type: application/postscript');
header('Location: appendix.ps');
```

but then, the link to this file has to have different name, so eventually I'm serving different file than in 'direct' link.
Is it possible to write a script `appendix.ps` which does something in the begining and then serves real `appendix.ps` file?
regards
chriss

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [readfile](https://www.php.net/readfile):

```
header('Content-type: application/postscript');
readfile('appendix.ps');
```

You also may want to send a "[Content-Disposition](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2183.txt)" header to hint to the user agent how its intended to be displayed.

If you want to suggest  to open it in a new window, Ie: trigger a download action:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment');
```

If you want to suggest to display it in the browser if it can:

```
header('Content-Disposition: inline');
```

Noting of course these are just *suggestions* and the browser may not play ball or even be able to, but they're handy to have.